# Async/Await. Parsing error: await is a reserved word. JS

Tags: javascript, async-await

I not so good familiar with Async/Await functions, that why I post this simple question. For some reasons it's does not let me go to compile my arrow function `activ`...

Please, help my if you can and do not joke...

```
let active = false;

const activ = async () => {
  return setTimeout(() => {
    if (setupCompleted) {
      active = true
      console.log('setupCompleted ACTIVATED', active);
    }
  }, 1500)
};

active = await activ; // Parsing error: await is a reserved word
```

Comment: Are you using eslint?

Comment: yes @J.Pichardo

Comment: await cannot be used outside of a function/method prefixed with async

Comment: and how can I make await my `active` variable until async func `activ`  finish own work? @GetOffMyLawn

Comment: where is activate defined?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn on the 1st string of the code in question

Comment: What your looking for in this case is a `Promise` not `async/await` you would then do `activ().then(...)`

Comment: If you want to use await, wrap the entire code block into a async (function(){... await ... })();